# Docker build stuck in npm install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

guys

I'm trying to build a node image of my project, but it get stucked on the npm install and i don't know why. I've searched everywhere but couldn't figure it out.

Using the tag --verbose, i see it gets stucked at logs (screenshot):

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --verbose

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5678

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

.dockerignore (it is in the root folder)

```
node_modules
product-api.log
jest.config.js
__test__
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest"
  },
  "name": "6---desafio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.29.3",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  }
}
```